# What is the purpose of `Data.Proxy`?

Tags: haskell, types

`Proxy` from [`Data.Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7/docs/Data-Proxy.html) seems to be nothing more than a mere

```
data Proxy s
```

When do I *need* such an uninhabited type or rather, what does it enable I couldn't do otherwise, when does it simplify things compared to other approaches, and how is it used in practice?

Comment: `Proxy s` is not an uninhabited type, it has a single constructor `Proxy`.

Comment: In particular, `Proxy` seems to actually be defined as `data Proxy s = Proxy` rather than `data Proxy s` as written in the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I frequently use `Proxy` with its partner in crime `Data.Tagged`, as the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.4.4) indicates, to avoid unsafely passing dummy arguments.

For example,

```
data Q

class Modulus a where
  value :: Tagged a Int

instance Modulus Q where
  value = Tagged 5

f x y = (x+y) `mod` (proxy value (Proxy::Proxy Q))
```

An alternative way to write that without `Tagged` is

```
data Q

class Modulus a where
  value :: Proxy a -> Int

instance Modulus Q where
  value _ = 5

f x y = (x+y) `mod` (value (Proxy::Proxy Q))
```

In both examples, we could also remove the `Proxy` type and just use an `undefined :: Q` to pass in the phantom type. However, using undefined is [generally frowned upon](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/haskell-is-exceptionally-unsafe/) because of the problems that can ensue if that value is ever evaluated. Consider the following:

```
data P = Three
       | Default

instance Modulus P where
  value Three = 3
  value _ = 5

f x y = (x+y) `mod` (value (undefined :: P))
```

which is a valid way to write the instance *if I use the `Default` constructor*, the program would crash since I'm trying to evaluate `undefined`. Thus the `Proxy` type gives type safety for phantom types.

**EDIT**

As Carl pointed out, another benefit of `Proxy` is the ability to have a phantom type of kind other than `*`. For example, I'm messing around with type lists:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeOperators, 
    MultiParamTypeClasses, PolyKinds, FlexibleContexts, 
    ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Tagged
import Data.Proxy

class Foo (a::[*]) b where
  foo:: Tagged a [b]

instance Foo '[] Int where
  foo = Tagged []

instance (Foo xs Int) => Foo (x ': xs) Int where
  foo = Tagged $ 1 : (proxy foo (Proxy :: Proxy xs)) -- xs has kind [*]

toUnary :: [Int]
toUnary = proxy foo (Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, Bool, String, Double, Float])
```

However, since `undefined` is a *value*, its type must have kind `*` or `#`. If I tried to use `undefined` in my example, I'd need something like `undefined :: '[Int, Bool, String, Double, Float]`, which results in the compile error:

```
Kind mis-match
    Expected kind `OpenKind',
    but '[Int, Bool, String, Double, Float] has kind `[*]'
```

For more on kinds, check [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Kinds) out. Given the error message, I expected to be able to write `undefined :: Int#`, but I still got the error `Couldn't match kind # against *`, so apparently this is a case of a poor GHC error message, or a simple mistake on my part.

Comment: As of recent versions of GHC, `Proxy` is also polykinded. You can say `Proxy :: Proxy Maybe`. Good luck saying `undefined :: Maybe`.

Comment: I don't think I'd consider a post on Robert Harper's blog as evidence of the Haskell community's standpoint on anything.  In particular, I doubt he'd consider using `Proxy` over `undefined` makes a significant difference in the safety of Haskell.  Not that it takes anything away from this answer, of course.

Comment: Why use `proxy` and not `unTagged`?

Comment: @coppro Usually you have to explicitly indicate the type of the tag. In rare cases this is not necessary, so you can get away with `unTagged`.