# Haskell FGL using Graph functions on a DynGraph

Tags: haskell, graph, typechecking

My goal is to do things with an intersection graph of shapes.  An intersection graph has nodes: shapes in R^n and there is an edge between nodes if they intersect.

In Haskell, one implements a function,

```
makeIntersectionGraph :: DynGraph g => [Shape] -> g Shape ()
makeIntersectionGraph sh = ... begin with the empty graph and add nodes and edges as you walk
                       ... through all possible intersections
```

The above compiles and typechecks fine.  A simple thing should be to get the nodes of the graph using the labNodes function.

```
getNodes sh = labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph sh)
```

Note that the documentation states:

> DynGraph: dynamic, extensible graphs. Dynamic graphs inherit all operations from static graphs but also offer operations to extend and change graphs.

and `labNodes` is a function for the `Graph` class.  So the above should work.

However, I get the error:

```
No instance for (Graph gr0) arising from a use of `labNodes'
    In the expression: labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph es)
    In an equation for `makeIntersectionGraphComplete':
        makeIntersectionGraphComplete es
          = labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph es)

DFN2Graph.hs:346:46:
    No instance for (DynGraph gr0)
      arising from a use of `makeIntersectionGraph'
    In the first argument of `labNodes', namely
      `(makeIntersectionGraph es)'
    In the expression: labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph es)
    In an equation for `makeIntersectionGraphComplete':
        makeIntersectionGraphComplete es
          = labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph es)
```

---- Update ----
I found a solution, but I don't understand what the problem is.  If I change the type

```
makeIntersectionGraph :: DynGraph g => [Shape] -> g Shape ()
```

To

```
makeIntersectionGraph ::  [Shape] -> G.Gr Shape ()
```

where

```
import qualified Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree as G
```

Then

```
getNodes sh = labNodes (makeIntersectionGraph sh)
```

works perfectly fine.  The problem I still have is that I don't see why it is necessary to invoke a concrete implementation of a DynGraph when all DynGraphs have access to the same functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with two functions: one that makes a graph, and one that consumes a graph. Let's simplify the types and ignore the `DynGraph`/`Graph` distinction for now.

```
makeGraph :: Graph g => [Shape] -> g Shape ()
makeGraph = undefined

consumeGraph :: Graph g => g Shape () -> [LNode Shape]
consumeGraph = undefined

f :: [Shape] -> [LNode Shape]
f = consumeGraph . makeGraph -- same as f x = consumeGraph (makeGraph x)
```

*Edit*: To split it out a bit:

```
f :: [Shape] -> [LNode Shape] -- Note: no g!
f shapes = consumeGraph g
  where g :: Graph g => g -- This annotation is just illustrative
        g = makeGraph shapes
```

The problem is that `g` doesn't appear in the type signature of `f`. The compiler could conceivably choose any of several types that satisfy the restriction, but that would be arbitrary and it won't do so.

The fact that all `Graph`s share the same functions doesn't really answer the question. Will the intermediate graph use a Patricia tree or a normal tree? It makes a difference. Imagine if we were talking about a class like `Num`: we could use `Int` or `Double` or `Integer` or `Decimal`, each with totally different performance *and semantic* characteristics.

So there needs to be some indication, somewhere, of which type you want. Your solution works; if you want to maintain the generality of `makeIntersectionGraph` you can use an internal type annotation, along these lines:

```
f' :: [Shape] -> [LNode Shape]
f' xs = consumeGraph (makeGraph xs :: G.Gr Shape)
```

This problem comes up often. I think of it as the "`show . read`" problem; that's a similar situation. What type do we use in the middle? [The Haskell '98 report has a section on "ambiguous types"](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), which also explains why this problem is *masked* by the default rules when you try to do this with `Num` functions.

(Note that in GHCi the [type defaulting rules are changed](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) from those specified in the '98 Report, which is why *in GHCi* `show . read` doesn't give a type error.)

Oh, I almost forgot about `DynGraph`/`Graph`. If you look at Haddock or the source, you'll see that `DynGraph` is defined as `class Graph gr => DynGraph gr where ...`. As a result, every `DynGraph` is also a `Graph`; the type signature `f :: DynGraph g => ...` allows you to use both `DynGraph` and `Graph` functions on the type `g`. In other words, that's not the problem you're encountering. The problem is that the compiler can't infer that the type `gr0` (which is the unstated intermediate type) is a member of *either* class.

*Edit*: To be more precise, actually *using* a class function requires either a class constraint or a specific type known to be a member of the class. Our functions `f` and `f'` are *monomorphic*; all the types are specified, and GHC should be able to generate actual, runnable code. But remember that class functions are defined per type; where can GHC go to get the class functions (the term here is "class dictionary") in `f`?

Specifying the type, like my `f'`, is one solution. You can also make the function itself *polymorphic*, in a kind of dependency-injection style. You'll need at least `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
f'' :: Graph g => proxy g -> [Shape] -> [LNode Shape]
f'' _ shapes = consumeGraph (makeGraph shapes :: g)
```

Notice that the first argument to the function doesn't need to actually exist; it's just a mechanism for callers to specify the type of `g`. A caller would use `Proxy` from `Data.Proxy`. There's a little discussion of `Proxy` in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116363/what-is-the-purpose-of-data-proxy) and many other places here and elsewhere.

Comment: On ghc 7.6.3, (show . read) /does/ give a compile time error.  So I guess the problem is that f:(Graph g) => (A -> g), and h : (Graph g) => g -> B cannot really be composed.  I was reading this as (A -> B) and (B -> C) then (A -> C), which should work.  B is really Gr g => g.  So can I say that the problem is that Haskell generates Gr g1 and Gr g2 and has no way of being able to unify gr1 with gr2?  Is there any way to force such an equality in the type system?

Comment: No, your `f` and `h` should be composable. Furthermore, I believe GHC *does* "unify" your `gr1` and `gr2`. It's not that the equality is missing. It's that GHC can't invent the class dictionary for `Graph` (i.e. all the functions defined in the `Graph` class instance for some specific type) without having an actual type--or a type variable!--to pull them from.